# I want to print out all the items but i only get the first

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I try to scrape this site:
https://www.notebook.hu/notebook/acer-notebook/aspire-sorozat

I was trying to collect all the item names from item-title div.
The problem is when I want to print them out I only get the first item.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.notebook.hu/notebook/acer-notebook/aspire- 
sorozat')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

cikkCimek = soup.find(class_='item-title')
cikkCimek_items = cikkCimek.find_all('a')

for cikkCimek in cikkCimek_items:
print(cikkCimek.prettify())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@chitown88 explained the problem and suggested `find_all()` with another `find_all()` in the inner loop. There is a more efficient way to do it in one go:

```
for cikkCimek in soup.select(".item-title a"):
    print(cikkCimek.prettify())
```

where `.item-title a` is a *CSS selector* matching all `a` elements inside elements with class `item-title`.

Comment: this is a much better solution. I'll have to remember `.select`

Comment: I would if it was my question. was just giving the nudge to @Csaba Kocsis. It is the better answer though

Comment: @chitown88 got mixed up with all of these answers and questions and it's too much :D

Comment: Thank you guys for the help.
I just started leraning programing maybe It is not the best way to start with webscraping but what can I do if this motivates me. :D

Comment: not a bad place to start at all! You'll have to learn all about lists, for loops, dictionaries/json structures, tables/dataframes...so have at it. and it's fun! You learn by doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
cikkCimek = soup.find(class_='item-title')
```

will only return the first element/block with class item-title. And in that first block is only one element with the tag `<a>`

change to `.find_all`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.notebook.hu/notebook/acer-notebook/aspire-sorozat')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

cikkCimek = soup.find_all(class_='item-title')


for elem in cikkCimek:
    cikkCimek_items = elem.find_all('a')
    for elem_items in cikkCimek_items:
        print(elem_items.prettify())
```